# How to retrieve columns of nested tables in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

This might be a basic question , but how do you retrieve 2nd column from inner table when using NOT  in function

For example  , i have 2 tables
Customer(Customer id , customername)
Orders (Order id , Order date , customerid)  , here customer id is a formatted foreign key

I am writing a query

```
select * 
from customer
where customerid not in (select case when '1' then substr(customerid,1,2)
                                     when '2' then substr(customerid , 1,3)
                                     else customerid 
                                     end  from Orders)
```

In this query , how do we retrieve Order id and Order date ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your case expression looks very strange. Case what is '1'?

Comment: I'd guess you want to JOIN the tables. (So you can return columns from both tables.) A [mcve] would make things much clearer.

Comment: Hm, what is "2nd column from inner table"? What is "inner table"?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try on this:

```
select customer.*, orders.orderid, orders.orderdate 
from customer 
full outer join 
(
  select case when substr(customerid,1,2) = '1' then substr(customerid,1,2)
              when substr(customerid,1,3) = '2' then substr(customerid,1,3)
              else customerid 
         end as customid
         , orderid, orderdate
  from Orders
) orders on (customer.customerid = orders.customid)
where customer.customerid is null
;
```

Example:

```
with customer as (
  select 'James' as name, '100' as customerid from dual 
  union all 
  select 'Mike' as name, '101' as customerid from dual 
  union all 
  select 'Steve' as name, '102' as customerid from dual 
  union all 
  select 'Nora' as name, '103' as customerid from dual 
),
orders as (
  select 1001 as orderid, TO_DATE('2020-06-01T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') as orderdate, '100' as customerid from dual 
  union all 
  select 1002 as orderid, TO_DATE('2020-07-21T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') as orderdate, '102' as customerid from dual 
  union all 
  select 1003 as orderid, TO_DATE('2020-07-22T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') as orderdate, '2' as customerid from dual 
  union all 
  select 1004 as orderid, TO_DATE('2020-06-05T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') as orderdate, '103' as customerid from dual 
  union all 
  select 1005 as orderid, TO_DATE('2020-06-05T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') as orderdate, '101' as customerid from dual 
)
select customer.*, orders.orderid, orders.orderdate 
from customer 
full outer join 
(
  select case when substr(customerid,1,2) = '1' then substr(customerid,1,2)
              when substr(customerid,1,3) = '2' then substr(customerid,1,3)
              else customerid 
         end as customid
         , orderid, orderdate
  from Orders
) orders on (customer.customerid = orders.customid)
where customer.customerid is null
;
```

Not exactly clear to me is your customer id formatted foreign key. Could you provide some examples, please?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select c.customerid, c.customername, o.id, o.date 
  from orders o, customer c 
 where not exists (select 1 
                     from orders o2 
                    where c.customerid = o2.customerid 
                      and o.id = o2.id);
```

Comment: read and post the answer ., 'In this query , how do we retrieve Order id and Order date' for this you need to use join